# VBSCript CreateObject variable uses an automation type not supported

Tags: vbscript, com

I have following error as soon I Create an object

```
Set myVariable = CreateObject("some.lib")
```

Error

```
variable uses an automation type not supported
```

I used google but couldn't find an answer what's wrong.
The Script worked few weeks ago without any problems

Comment: Has the compiled code for `some.lib` been altered at all?

Comment: Check your %PATH% to ensure any dependent libraries (of "some.lib") are being loaded from correct system folders, and maybe try launching your script using the 32-bit version of C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe (or wscript.exe).  Also, see if launching via another account context may have better luck -- which may indicate a profile or COM-registration problem.  Good luck.

Comment: It means that the "some.lib" object does not implement IDispatch .... or, being that it did work a few weeks ago, someone added a method to the interface that is not Automation compatible. I've seen this happen... You can create an interface that inherits from IDispatch, but then someone adds a method that has arguments that are not automation compatible...void*, IUnknown derived interface, etc.... and then it no longer is really IDispatch compatible. I've seen it barf more often on interprocess usage as opposed to inprocess usage. For non automation compatible args, create separate interface.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson yeah, it's the *"The Script worked a few weeks ago without any problems"* that threw me.